# Finding the exact time a webpage was published with source code

Tags: html, time, timezone

Wondering if someone could help me figure out the exact time + time zone a webpage was published.

2021-03-09T19:19:51.815Z

Can someone possible help?

Comment: Hey Joseph, I see that you are getting negative votes for your first post. I am sorry to see that but you need to try to come up with scenarios and problems where the community can see you have an effort to solve (researching first).

Answer (score 0):

This is an ISO-8601 Date format. It can be split into parts. Since you don't have a language tagged I'm not sure how to tell you to parse it.

- 2021 is the year
- 03 is the month (March)
- 09 is the date (9th day of March)
- T indicates the upcoming data is Time, it is always in 24hr clock.
- 19 is hour (7pm)
- 19 is the minutes
- 51 is the seconds
- 815 is the milliseconds
- Z indicates the date and time preceding it are in terms of Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

Comment: Your explanation of `Z` was incorrect.  I edited your answer to fix it.